# Alphabetical Insert in Double linked list issue

Tags: c, linked-list, alphabetical-sort

So, I am reading from a file and inserting national park names into nodesin a double linked list. Now, I want to insert alphabetically, and I thought I was doing that in the insert function, but when I go to print out the list, it is just in the order in which they are inserted in. My guess is that I have an error in the `strcmp` in the insert function, but I can't figure it out.

I am suppose to use sentinel nodes. So, the first node has `""` in it and the last node will have `177` in the data fields. This is my first time using sentinel nodes, and my teacher wanted us to use them, so I apologize if there is errors with them.

Thanks for the help.

```
#define DUMMY_TRAILER '\177'

    typedef struct node NODE;
    struct node
    {
        char data[20]; //for sentinel nodes
        char parkName[20];
        NODE *forw;
        NODE *back;
    };

    FILE *Open(void); // Opens file
    NODE *init_list(void); //Creates the sentinel nodes
    void insert(NODE *list, char *name); //Inserts nodes into list
    void traverse_forw(NODE *list); // Traverse the list and prints
```

**Main**

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        FILE* inputFile;
        NODE *list;
        char tempName[31];

        inputFile = Open();
        list = init_list();
        while(fgets(tempName, 31, inputFile) != NULL)
            {
                insert(list, tempName);
                FLUSH;
            }
        traverse_forw(list);

        free(list);

            return 0;
        }
```

**Insert Function**

```
        void insert(NODE *list, char *data)
            {
                NODE *curr = list->forw;
                NODE *prev = list;
                NODE *pnew;
                int duplicate = 1;

                // search
                while (strcmp(data,curr->data) > 0)
                {
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr->forw;
                }

                if (strcmp(data, curr->data))
                {
                    duplicate = 0; // not a duplicate
                    pnew = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof (NODE));
                    if (!pnew)
                    {
                        printf("Fatal memory allocation error in insert!\n");
                        exit(3);
                    }
                    strcpy(pnew->parkName, data);
                    pnew->forw = curr;
                    pnew->back = prev;
                    prev->forw = pnew;
                    curr->back = pnew;
                }
            return;
            }
```

**Traverse to print out park names**

```
void traverse_forw(NODE *list)
{
    putchar('\n');
    list = list->forw; // skip the dummy node
    while (list->data[0] != DUMMY_TRAILER)
    {
        printf("%s\n", list->parkName);
        list = list->forw;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing file read-lines into `parkName` but comparison is based on the `data` field

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create an empty linked list which is equal to NULL, then in the insert function before search, you control if the list is empty or not (in order to not comparing an string with NULL in the first insertion).

another issue is that in this part of the insert function:

```
            while (strcmp(data,curr->data) > 0)
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->forw;
            }
```

you are only controlling if the data is alphabetically after the current data, I mean you control only forward and if you insert a data which starts with "D" after a data which starts with "R" for instance, your code won't handle that. so you should also consider backward control as well.

Another issue is which pouyan mentioned above, that you are putting data into the data and not in the parkname.